# Error when running program using "node bot.js" in the terminal

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I was making a bot (here is my code)

```js
client.on('message', message => {   
    var msg = message.content.toLowerCase();
    if (msg.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
        var input = msg.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(' ');
        var command = input.shift();
        var commandArgs = input.join(' ');
    }
    var taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first();

    if (command === 'test') {
        // reply
        message.reply("hear you loud and clear")
    }  
});
```

but when I run it in the console with `"node bot.js"` after updating my node.js returns with this:

```
events.js:200
    throw new errors.ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('listener', 'Function', listener);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type Function. Received type undefined
    at _addListener (events.js:200:11)
    at Client.addListener (events.js:259:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myuser/SilencerBot/bot.js:6:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:733:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:300:19)
```

I'm not very advanced in Javascript so it would be very much appreciated if someone could tell me what went wrong. Thank you!

EDIT: Running the `node bot.js` command in the terminal after updating my `node.js` returned this error:

```
events.js:111

    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('listener', 'Function', listener);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received undefined
    at checkListener (events.js:111:11)
    at _addListener (events.js:348:3)
    at Client.addListener (events.js:406:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myUser/Bot/bot.js:6:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

What went wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you (especially Rak Laptudirm)!

Comment: You are doing arrow functions which is a valid syntax if your used node version supports it, ([examples here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/es6-syntax.html#template-literals)). Try to do normal functions, [example here](https://gist.github.com/koad/316b265a91d933fd1b62dddfcc3ff584) to see if problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `node.js` or `discord.js` is backdated. Please check if you are using the latest version. Also give a semicolon at the end of `message.reply()` and align your code properly, as it could be because of the Javascript automatic semicolon insertion. Also, try to declare the variables as constant as much as possible.

Also, you have used `msg.content.startsWith()`. `msg` is not a *message object*, it is a *string* according to your code:

```js
var msg = message.content.toLowerCase();`.
```

So use `msg.startsWith()`

Here is the new code:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
        
    var msg = message.content.toLowerCase();
    if (msg.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
        var input = msg.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(' ');
        var command = input.shift();
        var commandArgs = input.join(' ');
    }
    var taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first();

    if (command === 'test') {
        // reply
        message.reply("hear you loud and clear")
    }  
});
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: I checked and your problem is in the `msg` part, read my ans fo info.

Comment: . Also, if my answer helped pls mark it as accepted, so others can know.